# SOAP API username and password

Tags: api, soap-api, php, login

This might seam like a stupid question but I have run out of options.
Upon connecting to the SOAP API with SalesForce, I must provide a username and a password. I tried my credentials from the App Center, I tried the client secret and client ID, I tried even the credentials from the account from which I linked in the App Center, and also tried combinations and nothing worked.

So I guess my question is this: What is the username and password that are required to authenticate my app calls?

L.E: I am adding the token received via api call /requestToken and the token is STILL available. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SOAP API for login functionality ,please note that the Username and Password are your user credentials .

Also kindly note that password here is a combination of Password + Security Token .Your Security token is obtained from your personal settings .To avoid security token you can your php login server IP address in your trusted network settings inside SFDC.

Comment: What credentials? The app center ones? I tried those, do not work... the account that i linked in the app center? tried that and didn't work... What credentials?

Comment: I am trying and trying and every time I get "Login failed" and it is driving me crazy man, trust me...

Comment: Your SFDC credentials .Whats the error are you getting ? Also you can navigate to User record to check if login errors under login history

Comment: If you have admin credentials ,go to login history and see cause of login failure for your user .Its just password error or you are missing something obvious

Comment: I am simply getting "Login failed". Also, I tried those credentials from the platform that shows the login history (I think that is the SFDC that you are talking about) and they do not work. More so, I cannot see a failed login attempt in the login history :(( -- sorry, it is really frustrating...

Comment: It requires password reset then .Contact someone from your team who know SFDC to see if they can help you .Thanks

Comment: I am Sys admin on this account. Should I reset my own password? More so, does the sys admin has access to the API (is he API Enabled) or should I create another user for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38278/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-ares-draguna).